# How to get id in alertify confirm delete

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, alertify

Can anybody teach me how to get the id of a data in a row then pass into the delete.php. i dont know how to do this., im very new to this.. tnx alot.

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {

    echo $row['id'];
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    echo "<form id='form' action='delete.php'>";
    echo "<input type='button' value='submit' id='btn".$row['id']."' name='but'>";
    echo "<br>";

    echo "
    <script>
    $('#btn".$row['id']."').click(function() {
    alertify.confirm('Delete the selected entry?',function(e){
        if(e) {
            $('#form').submit();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    });
     });
     </script>
     ";
 }
```

Comment: Spread you logic and html firstly.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<form id='form'  action='delete.php'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='delete' value='' $row['id']."' >"; 
echo "<input type='button'  class='btn_del' >";
echo "<br>";
now in js

<script>
$('.btn").click(function() {
alertify.confirm('Delete the selected entry?',function(e){
if(e) {
$('#form').submit();
return true;
} else {
 return false;
}

});
});
</script>
then get value in delete.php by
$is=$_REQUEST['delete'];
// your query here
```

Comment: shoul i put this to delete.php file? -> $id =$POST_['delete'];

Comment: where u wana get the id and make some operation with id

Comment: it just delete the first row., when i delete the 2nd or 3rd  or 4th row it always delete the first row

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {

    echo $row['id'];
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    echo "<form id='form' action='delete.php'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='rowid' value='".$row['id']."' >"; 
    echo "<input type='button' value='submit' id='btn".$row['id']."'>";
    echo "</form><br>";

    echo "
    <script>
    $('#btn".$row['id']."').click(function() {
    alertify.confirm('Delete the selected entry?',function(e){
        if(e) {
            $('#form').submit();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    });
     });
     </script>
     ";
     }
```

In delete.php
Use `$_POST[rowid]` to get the value of row id to be deleted.